# System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException - On Large Message Size

Tags: wcf

I'm getting this exception on the client application, not sure how to get past this.
I encounter this exception when the data returned(A list of prices) exceeds 15MB, but works for message size less that 15MB.

**Error Message:**

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to "http://localhost:8782/CMDService". This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

**Trace O/P for client from TraceViewer:**

```
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>CMD.Web.Test.exe</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to "http://localhost:8782/CMDService". This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.</Message>
<StackTrace>

at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
at CMD.Client.Interface.ICMDService.GetData(String region, DateTime QuoteDate)
at CMD.Web.Test.Program.TestGetData()
at CMD.Web.Test.Program.Main(String[] args)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to "http://localhost:8782/CMDService". This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.  System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.WebException, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---&gt; System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.IO.IOException, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)</ExceptionString>
<NativeErrorCode>2746</NativeErrorCode>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
```

**Tracing on the service did not report any exceptions**

**Config on both service and client are identical**

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CMDServiceBinding"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 closeTimeout="00:10:00" 
                 openTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">

          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>

<behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="UBS.Firc.Broil.CMD.QuotesServiceBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
         </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I solved my issue as I explained here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537794/error-while-deserializing-the-object-in-wcf/8415908#8415908

Answer (score 8):

Briefly in behaviors you have serviceBehavior and endpointBehavior. You should write something like this:

```
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="10000000"/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />            
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
```

Hoping that helps !

Comment: I was getting the same error in my application so I set up tracing (instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx)) which showed a much more descriptive error message which pointed me to this solution.

Answer (score 8):

**Hope It may help you...**

```
<bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IVtmWebResolution" maxBufferSize="2147483647" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
```

**Happy Coding**

Answer (score 7):

If your service was hosted by ASP.NET, you might have to increase ASP.NET's max upload size:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>
```